# AWS Lambda Deployment - AccessDeniedException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

i have deployed a aws lambda app that uses dynamodb but when i run the lambda fuction i am getting following errors

```
START RequestId: 325ce8ea-ed86-404c-8756-ee46dbefae35 Version: $LATEST
2021-12-20T06:32:08.533Z    325ce8ea-ed86-404c-8756-ee46dbefae35    ERROR   query-error: AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::579450367668:assumed-role/lead-management-app-dev-eu-west-1-lambdaRole/lead-management-app-dev-submitLeadForm is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:579450367668:table/lead-management-app-leads-dev/index/emai_index
END RequestId: 325ce8ea-ed86-404c-8756-ee46dbefae35
REPORT RequestId: 325ce8ea-ed86-404c-8756-ee46dbefae35  Duration: 14.83 ms  Billed Duration: 15 ms  Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 81 MB
```

how can i solve this issue ?

I am attching my serverless.ts below

```
   /* eslint no-use-before-define: 0 */
    
    import type { AWS } from "@serverless/typescript";
    
    // DynamoDB
    import dynamoDbTables from "./resources/dynamodb-tables";
    
    // Functions
    import functions from "./resources/functions";
    
    const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
      service: "lead-management-app",
      frameworkVersion: "2",
      custom: {
        region: "${opt:region, self:provider.region}",
        stage: "${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}",
        prefix: "${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}",
        lead_table: "${self:service}-leads-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}",
        interest_table:
          "${self:service}-interests-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}",
        table_throughputs: {
          prod: 5,
          default: 1,
        },
        table_throughput:
          "${self:custom.table_throughputs.${self:custom.stage}, self:custom.table_throughputs.default}",
        dynamodb: {
          stages: ["dev"],
          start: {
            port: 8008,
            inMemory: true,
            heapInitial: "200m",
            heapMax: "1g",
            migrate: true,
            seed: true,
            convertEmptyValues: true,
            // Uncomment only if you already have a DynamoDB running locally
            // noStart: true
          },
        },
        ["serverless-offline"]: {
          httpPort: 3000,
          babelOptions: {
            presets: ["env"],
          },
        },
        profile: {
          prod: "prodAccount",
          dev: "devAccount",
        },
      },
      plugins: [
        "serverless-bundle",
        "serverless-dynamodb-local",
        "serverless-offline",
        "serverless-dotenv-plugin",
      ],
      provider: {
        name: "aws",
        runtime: "nodejs14.x",
        stage: "dev",
        region: "ap-south-1",
        apiGateway: {
          minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
          shouldStartNameWithService: true,
        },
        environment: {
          AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: "1",
          NODE_OPTIONS: "--enable-source-maps --stack-trace-limit=1000",
          REGION: "${self:custom.region}",
          STAGE: "${self:custom.stage}",
          LEADS_TABLE: "${self:custom.lead_table}",
          INTERESTS_TABLE: "${self:custom.interest_table}",
        },
        iamRoleStatements: [
          {
            Effect: "Allow",
            Action: [
              "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
              "dynamodb:Query",
              "dynamodb:Scan",
              "dynamodb:GetItem",
              "dynamodb:PutItem",
              "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
              "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
            ],
            Resource: [
              { "Fn::GetAtt": ["LeadsTable", "Arn"] },
              { "Fn::GetAtt": ["InterestsTable", "Arn"] },
            ],
          },
        ],
        profile: "${self:custom.profile.${self:custom.stage}}",
        lambdaHashingVersion: "20201221",
      },
      // import the function via paths
      functions,
      package: { individually: true },
      resources: {
        Resources: dynamoDbTables,
      },
    };
    
    module.exports = serverlessConfiguration;
```

can this be solved through the app or should i grant the permission form aws console?

are there any recommended permission list that i should grant ?

Comment: The role that is used to execute the lambda function is not allowed to access the dynamodb table. Add the according permissions to the lambda execution role

Comment: @derpirscher thanks , can this be done through my app ? or should it be set through aws console ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to attach the following permission (at least, and probably more) to the role `lead-management-app-dev-eu-west-1-lambdaRole`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:Query"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:579450367668:table/lead-management-app-leads-dev/index/emai_index",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you're doing this within the AWS console, you can locate the Execution role within Permissions/Configuration for the Lambda function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can this be done through my app ? . I have added my serverless.ts where i specify the permissions  to the question

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the serverless framework, but, based on the link provided by @Anss below, you could try modifying the following
`Resource: [
    { "Fn::GetAtt": ["LeadsTable", "Arn"] }
]`

to something like: 

`Resource: [
    { "Fn::Join": ["", [ { "Fn::GetAtt": ["LeadsTable", "Arn"] }, "/index/emai_index" ] ] }
]`

Answer (score 3):

The role assumed by your lambda function does not have required permissions to access the Dynamo Db table. To solve this, you need to attach the appropriate policy to your lambda function role.

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_lambda-access-dynamodb.html) page contains a policy that grants Read/Write access to your lambda function.

Comment: @Anns can this be done through my severless app ?

Comment: @coderman If you are using AWS SAM for developing your serverless application then yes, it is defined in this article https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-sam-template-permissions/.

Comment: @coderman And if you are using serverless framework then you can follow this link: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam